# Sharepoint table/list

Tags: list, page-layout

I am new-ish to developing SharePoint sites so please bear with me. I have a requirement to create a site with a spreadsheet-like layout for recording employees hence columns for name, surname, address etc and a few drop down menus for the users to select predefined job title, department etc.
Any advise for the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple: in SharePoint, everything is a list. Think of a list as a SQL table, i.e. it types columns (integer, text, date time, choice...) that define what can be stored in the list. And each row is a record in the list.
(note: technically speaking, a SharePoint list is *not* a SQL table, even if all data are stored in SQL, but it's not a 1-1 relationship between the 2 concepts).

So, in your case you would create a new custom list (i.e. a list with no pre-defined column, except for the "Title" column that is mandatory but that you can rename). In this list you would add the columns (aka fields or properties) you need, including choice columns that will be displayed as dropdown lists when users create new records (aka items) in the list.

Google for [*SharePoint list*](https://www.google.fr/search?q=sharepoint%20list) and [*SharePoint column types*](https://www.google.fr/search?q=sharepoint%20columns%20types) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is how i am currently configuring it but wanted to check this is the best option. Im sure i have seen it before though in a grid view with lines on the table and the headers much bolder, i assume this is simply HTML customization?

Comment: The "Grid view" is the same list displayed differently. You can access to the grid view by selecting "Quick edit" from the ribbon, in the "List" tab (SharePoint on-premises) or "Quick edit" in the toolbar (SharePoint Online).